# How to change vscode pushing code to master branch to main branch?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

When I am trying to push my code, vscode issues the command `git push origin main:master` instead of `git push origin main`. How do I change it?

Comment: What is the output of `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref main@{upstream}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change your local `main` branch to track `origin/main` instead of `origin/master`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
```

Answer (score 3):

Click on the "..." sign in source control and select "Pull, Push">"Push to...".

You'll be prompted to select the branch to push to.
[image]

Comment: I solved the problem using the previous answer. But I think `Push to` only shows `origin` and not the branch. Maybe because there is no master branch in github ?

Comment: You have to do that EVERY time though. I don't see any way to make it a default from in Vscode.

Answer (score 0):

One way to set your default branch is to edit your default user account  `~/.gitconfig` file. Add the following lines:

```
[init]
  defaultBranch = main
```